# Angular -unit test case - jasmine and karma - more then 5k testcases - browser crashes

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

In my angular application,i have around more then 5K test cases.In integration, my test cases fails after ~1200.I found reason that,for each test case i have beforeEach block and i am using $digest in this block.So my browser runner get crashed due to memory leak.I want to use one time $digest cycle with the pre complied scope object.

Source :

```
 beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
         suite = {};
             suite.$rootScope = $rootScope;
             suite.$compile = $compile;
             suite.scope = $rootScope.$new();


             suite.element = suite.$compile('<div test-directive config = "config"></div>')(suite.scope);
             suite.scope.$digest();
             suite.directiveScope = suite.element.isolateScope();
             suite.controllerInstance =suite.directiveScope.testctrl;
     }
 ));

     //NOTE: still needed cleanup
     afterEach(function() {
        suite.directiveScope.$destroy();
        suite.element.remove();
        suite=null;

     });
```

Note : Browser memory is not destroying.It is increasing upto 80% and browser get crashed.Help me pls.